# Styled EditText inside a compound view doesn't gain focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme

I have made a very simple compound view:

```
<LinearLayout>
   <ImageView />
   <EditText />
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything worked fine until I have decided to style the Edit text throught my project:theme:

```
    <style name="Theme.MyProject" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Theme.MyProject.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/Widget.Playout.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Theme.Theme.MyProject.Button</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Theme.Theme.MyProject.EditText</item>
    </style>
```

and

```
<style name="Theme.Playout.EditText">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/field_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/field</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>
```

Now my EditText is beautiful but is not gaining focus so text cannot being entered (so useful). It works fine adding values directly to the Compound view from layout but I whould like to do it from a confortable theme.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style name="Theme.Playout.EditText">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/field_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/field</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>

    <!-- I added these attributes: -->
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, I had tried with 'focusable' but not with 'focusableInTouchMode'